# regex for extracting data in the middle of a string that has preceding comma + space and ends with space + (capital X)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that I am trying to use regex to extract from. Here is the example of my string:

```
splitm = 'SM Analyst, AMT Tax Company X Hi.'
```

I want to parse out the name as `"SM Analyst"`, The company as `"AMT Tax Company"` and the data after `X` as `"Hi."`

My regex for parsing the name is as below:

```
x = re.match('^.*?\,', splitm)
```

For the company I am trying: (everything after the comma but it isn't working)
`y = re.match('^\,(.*?)', splitm)`.

Any pointers on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: As to answer what you are doing wrong is that ^ matches at the start of the string, and there is no comma at the start of the string. See infinity's answer below for one of the possible solutions. PS, you dont need to escape comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caret (^) matches the position before the first character in the string.

This is not necessary if you don't use `re.MULTILINE`, because you use [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at **the beginning** of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.

### Solution

We can use named groups to catch the relevant parts in a single regular expression, then to use [`groupdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) to get the results as a dictionary:

```py
import re

REGEX = r'(?P<role>.+?),\s+(?P<company>.+?)\s+X\s+(?P<message>.+)'
re.match(REGEX, "SM Analyst, AMT Tax Company X Hi.").groupdict()
```

> `{'role': 'SM Analyst', 'company': 'AMT Tax Company', 'message': 'Hi.'}`

Comment: Might be worth replacing the spaces with `\s+`.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. I also dint realize you can create a key value pair (dict) using regex so definitely new learning from me. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

splitm = 'SM Analyst, AMT Tax Company X Hi.'

print(re.findall('(?<=, ).*(?= [A-Z] )',splitm)) # Find string that is between a ', ' and a uppercase letter that has a space on both sides
print(re.findall('(?<= )\w+\.',splitm)) # Find word character string that is between a ' ' and a '.'
```

Output:

```
['AMT Tax Company']
['Hi.']
```